# Xpath to find URLs that don't start with http/s

Tags: xpath, domxpath

I am trying to write an Xpath to extract URLs used in both @href or @src attributes that are relative (URLs that don't start with http:// or https://).

I have used the below but it's not working:

```
//*[not(starts-with(@src, 'https:')) and not(starts-with(@href, 'https:'))]
```

Example node:

```
<script async="" src="//d.impactradius-event.com/A2421746-f56c-44ad-9e09-bcf28112e9951.js"></script>
```

I wish to pull src URL. Can someone please help? Thanks.

Comment: Post a [mcve] and also define "not working".

Comment: Please don't tell us something "isn't working". Tell us exactly how it fails. Diagnosing a problem always starts with a description of the symptoms.

Comment: It's too much of an HTML that's being scraped with the given Xpath in my original which unfortunately can't be pasted here. I can share a link where I am trying to run it but that'd perhaps be marked spam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following XPath-1.0 expression. It checks both attributes for both strings and then merges the output with the `|` operator.

```
//*[not(starts-with(@src, 'https:')) and not(starts-with(@src, 'http:'))]/@src | //*[not(starts-with(@href, 'https:')) and not(starts-with(@href, 'http:'))]/@href
```

This expression could be simplified with RegEx'es, but XPath-1.0 doesn't support this.

Comment: Won't this return all elements that don't have an `@src` or `@href` attribute?

Comment: Good question. So I pondered, and tested it to make sure, and it turns out: no, because the first parts of both expressions would indeed return all elements without `@src` and `@href` attributes, but after the predicate the second part selects only the respective `/@src` and `/@href` attributes. So the whole expression can only return `@src` and `@href` attributes at all.